# How to make 2 spans inside div in one line so that content from next div doesn't go to the place of first div?

Tags: html, css

You'll see that images from div `.second` go upper than last image from div `.first` so they go just in the next line from span `.text`. What can I do to make images from div `.second` to go in the next line from images of div `.first` and not in the next line of span `.text`?

```html
<div id="first" style="display: block;">
    <span style="display: inline; float: left">
        <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
        <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
        <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    </span>
    <span id="text" style="display: inline;">
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some text</div>
        <div>some text</div>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
    <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would advice you to use bootstrap grid with offset.

Comment: First, your code is invalid. Second, you're using multiple ways (all wrong) to have the different elements behave in some sort of way... Okay, first: `<div>` is by default `display: block;` -no need to assign it. Second, you're using `<div>` inside a `<span>` which you shouldn't. Either make those `<span>`s into `<div>`, or the inside `<div>`s into `<span>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but try this (just added the clear: both on the second div):

```
<div id="first" style="display: block;">
<span style="display: inline; float: left">
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
</span>
<span id="text" style="display: inline;">
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
</span>
</div>
<div id="second" style="clear: both">
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also. take not of @junkfoodjunkie recommendations. you should be using divs instead of spans there.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I needed, however, I did same thing using other styles, I'll post my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible:

```
<div id="first" style="display: inline-block;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; float: left;">
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
<div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
</span>
  <span id="text" style="display: inline-block;">
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
</span>
</div>
<div id="second" style="dispaly: inline-block;">
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
  <div><img width="300" height="225"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version - although I suspect that all of those containers (the inner `<div>`s) should be `<ul>`s - they seem like lists to me) - also the `#second` `<div>` probably. This uses `display: flex;` for the inline ones, to make sure they fill up the width of the container.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
#first,#second {
  width: 100%;
  }
#first {
  display: flex;
  }
#second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
.images, .text {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div class="images">
    <img width="300" height="225" alt="first image"><br>
    <img width="300" height="225" alt="second image"><br>
    <img width="300" height="225" alt="third image"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second first image"><br>
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second second image"><br>
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second third image"><br>
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second fourth image"><br>
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second fifth image"><br>
  <img width="300" height="225" alt="second sixth image"><br>
</div>
```